# why Custom Pipe Doesn't work with local Template variables in Angular 2

Tags: angular, pipe

I have a Pipe just for Example that Squares the value that it receives this below one works fine

Template

```
<input type = "number" placeholder = "Enter number for which square is to be calculated" [(ngModel)] = "value">
  <p>Squared Number is using pipe Transform  {{value | square}} </p>
```

Component

```
value = 2;
```

Custom Pipe

```
import { Pipe,PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name:'square'
})

export class SquarePipe implements PipeTransform{
  transform(value: number, args?: number[]): number {
    return Math.pow(value, 2);
  }

}
```

But when i try to use the template like this

it doesn't work I need to know why ?

```
<input type = "number" placeholder = "Enter number for which square is to be calculated" #value>
  <p>Squared Number is using pipe Transform  {{value | square}} </p>
```

Comment: Have you some console errors?

Comment: @JaroslawK. No errors the Pipe won't work

Comment: What does "doesn't work mean exactly"?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Doesn't work means the Pipe fails to do its job of filtering in the view and no error also in the console

Comment: What happens? Have you tried to just `return value;` in `transform()`? What do you mean with "local Template variable"? A template variable usually is `<div #myTemplateVar></div>`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer if you check the last part of the question <input type = "number" #value> . i am refering to #value as a local template value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want is

```
<p>Squared Number is using pipe Transform  {{value.value | square}} </p>
```

`value` alone refers to the `HTMLInputElement`